Documents after surname change
I am a citizen of Ukraine and I entered European Union with one Ukrainian passport and then changed it to another one with a new surname. Am I getting in trouble after leaving Schengen area? What should I do?
P.s. I am in Austria

If you have a residence permit, you must inform the immigration offlice about the new passport and name change.
